# Send float32 values over udp socket

Tags: sockets, go, udp, type-conversion

I'm working on a Go project and I would like to send float32 values using an UDPSocket.
The thing that I don't understand is what is the best way to convert these numbers to a byte buffer before sending them and how to convert them back to float32 after receiving them.

At the moment I'm converting float32->[]byte with the following function that I've found online, but I'm not even sure I'm getting what I want:

```
func Float32bytes(float float32) []byte {
    bits := math.Float32bits(float)
    bytes := make([]byte, 4)
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(bytes, bits)
    return bytes
}
```

I still don't know how to convert them to float32.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func Float32Bytes(float float32) []byte {
    bits := math.Float32bits(float)
    bytes := make([]byte, 4)
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(bytes, bits)
    return bytes
}

func BytesFloat32(bytes []byte) float32 {
    bits := binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(bytes)
    float := math.Float32frombits(bits)
    return float
}

func main() {
    pi := float32(math.Pi)
    b := Float32Bytes(pi)
    f := BytesFloat32(b)
    fmt.Println(f, f == pi, BytesFloat32(Float32Bytes(pi)) == pi)
}
```

Output:

```
3.1415927 true true
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to work fine. I still haven't achieved what I needed from my code, but the conversion works! Many thanks!