# How to convert bytes to a float32 array in Go?

Tags: python, go, floating-point, type-conversion

I am writing an array of float32 numbers from a Python script to an Elasticache Redis cluster in bytes format, then reading the bytes (as a string) from Elasticache in a Go script. How do I convert the bytes-as-string back to the original float32 array in the Go script?

Python example:

```
import numpy as np
import redis
a = np.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3], dtype=np.float32)
a_bytes = a.tobytes(order="C") #I have also tried order="F" with no luck
print(a_bytes) #Output: b'\xcd\xcc\x8c?\xcd\xcc\x0c@33S@'
redis_client = redis.cluster.RedisCluster(host=<elasticache config endpoint>, port=6379)
redis_client.mset_nonatomic({"key1": a_bytes})
```

Here's an example of what I've tried in Go ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/LRWszHuYFvA))

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    // aBytesStr is an example value retrieved from Elasticache
    // aBytesStr is type string, not raw bytes
    var aBytesStr string = "\xcd\xcc\x8c?\xcd\xcc\x0c@33S@"
    aHex := fmt.Sprintf("%X", aBytesStr)
    fmt.Println(aHex) // Output: CDCC8C3FCDCC0C4033335340
    var aArr [3]float32
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        aHex1 := aHex[i*8 : i*8+8]
        aParsed, err := strconv.ParseUint(aHex1, 16, 32)
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        aArr[i] = math.Float32frombits(uint32(aParsed))
    }
    fmt.Println(aArr)
    // Expected output: [1.1 2.2 3.3]
    // Actual output [-4.289679e+08 -4.2791936e+08 4.17524e-08]
}
```

Comment: Does `a2 = np.frombuffer(a_bytes, dtype=np.float32)` work?

Comment: @JonSG Yes, that's how the conversion would work in Python. I am trying to do the conversion in Go.

Comment: ah, sorry I thought you were looking for a python solution

Comment: Your code is nearly correct, but it's using big endian values where Python produced little endian values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example code you are using is to "convert hex, represented as strings"; you have the raw bytes (I think based on `aHex: CDCC8C3FCDCC0C4033335340`) so its simpler to convert directly (while you could convert the bytes to a hex string, and then convert that, doing so just adds unnecessary work/complexity).

Drawing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33329424/11810946) we get ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/ik5SgG8d3WI)):

```
func GetFloatArray(aBytes []byte) []float32 {
    aArr := make([]float32, 3)
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        aArr[i] = BytesFloat32(aBytes[i*4:])
    }
    return aArr
}

func BytesFloat32(bytes []byte) float32 {
    bits := binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(bytes)
    float := math.Float32frombits(bits)
    return float
}
```

Update ref comment:

> I convert the bytes-as-string to a hex string, to a []bytes, to []float32. Is there a way to directly convert the bytes-as-string to []bytes?

I'm still a bit confused about what you are receiving so lets work through both possibilities.

If the redis query is returning raw data (bytes) as a go string (i.e. `"\xcd\xcc\x8c?\xcd\xcc\x0c@33S@"`) then you can just [convert](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions_to_and_from_a_string_type) this to `[]byte` ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/rhVUFUl_1I7))

```
func main() {
    var aBytesStr string = "\xcd\xcc\x8c?\xcd\xcc\x0c@33S@"
    fmt.Println(GetFloatArray([]byte(aBytesStr)))
}
```

If redis is returning a string containing an ASCII (/UTF-8) representation (i.e. `CDCC` = `[]byte{0x41, 0x44, 0x43, 0x43}`) the simplest approach is probably to use [encoding/hex](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/hex#DecodeString) to decode this ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/ylRQiiis20R))

```
func main() {
    aHex := "CDCC8C3FCDCC0C4033335340"
    b, err := hex.DecodeString(aHex)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(GetFloatArray(b))
}
```

Note that your original approach could work but, as pointed out in the comments above, you need to deal with [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) so the following will work ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/N9fMA54BUOu) - you could make this more efficient, I aimed for clarity):

```
byte1 := aHex[i*8 : i*8+2]
byte2 := aHex[i*8+2 : i*8+4]
byte3 := aHex[i*8+4 : i*8+6]
byte4 := aHex[i*8+6 : i*8+8]
aParsed, err := strconv.ParseUint(byte4+byte3+byte2+byte1, 16, 32)
```

However this makes assumptions about the CPU the code is running on which means the previous answer is preferable.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to use this to solve my problem so I accepted this answer. In my question I neglected to specify that I wasn't getting raw bytes from Elasticache but a string representation of the raw bytes. I have clarified my question and given a minimal reproducible example. My current solution is here: https://go.dev/play/p/Uj5_BpjGnEy

Comment: In my current solution, I convert the bytes-as-string to a hex string, to a []bytes, to []float32. Is there a way to directly convert the bytes-as-string to []bytes?